# Drop rows in pandas if they contains "???"

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to drop rows in pandas that contains "???", it works for every other value except for "???", I do not know whats the problem.

This is my code (I have tried both types):

```
df = df[~df["text"].str.contains("?????", na=False)]
df = df[~df["text"].str.contains("?????")]
```

error that I'm getting:

```
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

It works for every other value except for "????".
I have googled it, and looked all over this website but I couldnt find any solutions.

Comment: `?` is a regular expression special character. Do instead: `df = df[~df["text"].str.contains("?????",regex=False)]`

Comment: Now im getting an error: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: don't use regex or escape it or put in `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter expects a regular expression, hence the error `re.error`.
You can either escape the ? inside the expression like this:

```
df = df[~df["text"].str.contains("\?\?\?\?\?")]
```

Or set `regex=False` as Vorsprung sugested:

```
df = df[~df["text"].str.contains("?????",regex=False)]
```

Comment: Now im getting an error: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: @taga When using that to filter you should always use `na=False` as an argument, that way you're not accidentally slicing with a Series that might contain `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

let's convert this into running code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['abc', 'cxx???xx', '???',], 'B': ['add', 'ddb', 'c', ]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

output:

```
    A   B
0   abc add
1   cxx???xx    ddb
2   ??? c
```

with this:

```
df[df['A'].str.contains('???',regex=False)]
```

output:

```
    A   B
1   cxx???xx    ddb
2   ??? c
```

you need to tell `contains()`, that your search string is not a regex.