# Drop row in pandas if it contains condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to drop rows in pandas based on whether or not it contains "/" in the cells in column "Price". I have referred to the question: [Drop rows in pandas if they contains "???"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034172/drop-rows-in-pandas-if-they-contains).

As such, I have tried both codes:

`df = df[~df["Price"].str.contains('/')]`

and

`df = df[~df["Price"].str.contains('/',regex=False)]`

However, both codes give the error: 
`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

For reference, the first few rows of my dataframe is as follows:

```
    Fruit   Price
0   Apple     3
1   Apple    2/3
2   Banana    2
3   Orange   6/7
```

May I know what went wrong and how can I fix this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: what is the data type of Price, is it str?

Comment: Call ``dtype`` and see what's its dtype and try casting to string if its not a string using ``astype``

Comment: Oh it is an object. I've tried to use astype but it's still an object

Comment: `object` is ok. I think this column have NaN values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df[~df['Price'].astype(str).str.contains('/')]
print(df)

    Fruit Price
0   Apple     3
2  Banana     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the price column to string first and then apply this operation. I believe that price column doesn't have datatype string

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(str)
```

and then try

```
df = df[~df["Price"].str.contains('/',regex=False)]
```